# Connecting to Oracle database in windows server 2003 from amazon ubuntu 10.04 instance

Tags: mysql, oracle, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2003, ubuntu-10.04

I have an oracle database in windows 2003 server.

I have created an amazon instance (ubuntu 10.04).
Here,I have to run some kettle jobs which populate data to mysql database from oracle database.

i.e when the kettle job is started,it should access the oracle database in windows server
and populate my destination database in mysql.

But I don't know how to connect to the oracle database.

I'm using JNDI connection to access both my source and destination databases.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a ODBC connection ?

**Connecting to an Oracle database via and ODBC driver requires the following steps:**

- Install the ODAC (Oracle Data Access Components) or Oracle Client on
  the Workstation or application Server.
- Setup the SQLNET and TNSNAMES files in the Client or ODAC home’s
  Admin directory.
- Use the ODBC Data Source configuration tools to create the ODBC Data
  Source.

To download the ODAC go to [Oracle ODAC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)
 This can be done in windos and linux as well !